# Ionic/AngularJS display issues

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a few issues and just wondering how to correct them.

1) I have data displaying in a list, but it's not displaying "WYSIWYG."  I have "It's A New Day" but it displays the ' in it's as &8217 and a semi colon.

2) I am fetching JSON data and in the string, it has a p tag and that tag is displaying in the result display.  I don't want to show the tags, just text.

Comment: It sounds like you have HTML stored in your data?   Can you show a sample of your data and the code you are using?  In general, you shouldn't have HTML in your data values.

Comment: if you have no other alternative than to store HTML in your variables (user generated content) then you will need to use `ng-sanitize` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize.  HTML isn't normally displayed, due to the potential for malicious content.

Comment: For #2 on my question, look at the "description" in the json data:
http://genesis2media.com/mobile/espresso-api/v1/events/public.pretty_json/

Comment: Regarding #1, there isn't any HTML.  It's simply a title post from wordpress.